# Trying to use MySQL protocol support and SphinxQL

Tags: mysql, sphinx

But unluckily it seems I can't get the layer to work, all I see are my local mysql databases, what am I doing wrong? of course I'm connecting to the correct port.

It seems that I connect to the default mysql server even if I give a non existant port

Comment: Ok, I've found the solution, unluckily while using mysql CLI on the same host it goes directly to the mysql.sock, you have to add -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3454

Answer (score 3):

Another option to force mysql to connect to the specified port and ignore the socket is to specify the `--protocol` option explicitly.

I have searchd (SphinxQL) listening on port 9306. To connect:
`mysql --port=9306 --protocol=tcp`

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html